# Case Query in LINQ equivalent to sql query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a dataset that contains caller, callee fiels and i need some LINQ query to operate on this dataset equivalent to this sql query

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN caller < callee THEN callee
     ELSE caller
   END      AS caller1,
   CASE
     WHEN caller < callee THEN caller
     ELSE callee
   END      AS caller2,
   Count(*) AS [Count]
    FROM   YourTable
   GROUP  BY CASE
        WHEN caller < callee THEN callee
        ELSE caller
      END,
      CASE
        WHEN caller < callee THEN caller
        ELSE callee
      END
```

Comment: `Dataset` means [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)?

Comment: I mean .net dataset that contains a datatable .

Comment: Both caller and callee are of string type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("dataTable");

dataTable.Columns.Add("caller", typeof(String));
dataTable.Columns.Add("callee", typeof(String));

dataTable.Rows.Add("999", "888");
dataTable.Rows.Add("888", "999");
dataTable.Rows.Add("999", "555");
dataTable.Rows.Add("555", "333");
dataTable.Rows.Add("555", "999");

dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

string filter = "999";

var result = dataSet.Tables["dataTable"].Select().Select(dr =>
    new
    {
        caller1 = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(dr["caller"], dr["callee"]) < 0 ? dr["callee"] : dr["caller"],
        caller2 = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(dr["caller"], dr["callee"]) < 0 ? dr["caller"] : dr["callee"]
    })
        .Where(dr => String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) || dr.caller1 == filter || dr.caller2 == filter)
        .GroupBy(drg => new { drg.caller1, drg.caller2 } )
        .Select(drg => new { drg.Key.caller1, drg.Key.caller2, count = drg.Count() });
```

Comment: Hi if i need to get only those caller details whoose no is 999 how can i achieve in this query

Comment: Do wyou want to filter the results at the dataTable level (i.e. only callers that are "999" but not callees that are "999") or do you want to the data from the result (i.e. caller1 that are "999")?

Comment: both caller1 and caller2 can be 999

Comment: I have edited the answer for your filtering scenario. Note that I presumed that the lack of filter should return all results. If that's incorrect, remove `String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) ||` from the where clause to return no results instead.

Comment: If i add date column in datatable , and wanna get max and min date in result set. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for, note the use of range variables which helps us reuse the case statement and simplify the LINQ query.

```
var query = from y in YourTable
            //place the result of the case statement into a range variable so we can reuse it for the grouping
            let caller1 = y.caller < y.callee ? y.callee : y.caller
            let caller2 = y.caller < y.callee ? y.caller : y.callee
            //group the results
            group y by new { caller1, caller2 } into grouping
            select new
            {            
                //get the range variables from the grouping key
                grouping.Key.caller1,
                grouping.Key.caller2,
                //get the count of the grouping
                Count = grouping.Count(),
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN caller < callee THEN callee
  ELSE caller
END      AS caller1
```

is translated into

```
caller1 = x.caller < x.callee ? x.callee : x.caller
```